# Calling @JSFunction from JavaScript, TypeError: Cannot find default value for object

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm calling a `@JSFunction` annotated method of a `ScriptableObject`

The JavaScript file

```
Target = Packages.com.acme.rhino.Target;

function evaluate() {
    var t = Target();
    t.addModifier("foobar", 1);
    return t;
}
```

The Java File

```
public class Target extends ScriptableObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public List<Modifier> modifiers = new LinkedList<>();

    @JSConstructor
    public Target() {
    }

    @JSFunction
    public void addModifier(final String message, final int value) {
        modifiers.add(new Modifier(message, value));
    }

    public int getValue() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (final Modifier modifier : modifiers) {
            sum += modifier.getValue();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return "Target";
    }
}
```

But I get

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object.
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3705)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getDefaultValue(ScriptableObject.java:976    )
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getDefaultValue(ScriptableObject.java:895    )
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.toString(ScriptRuntime.java:761)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3774)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.    java:2269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.    java:2251)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:83)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.script_5._c_evaluate_1(script:6)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.script_5.call(script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.script_5.call(script)
```

and don't know where to go from there. When I don't call `addModifier` method the given code works, and given the error `notFunctionError` down in the stack trace I think that Rhino doesn't interpret the given method as a JavaScript Function.

- OSX 10.8.2
- Java 7
- Rhino 1.7R4

Complete Maven project that reproduces the error can be found [here](https://github.com/oschrenk/stackoverflow-q14561874)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr see [these](https://github.com/tschaub/stackoverflow-q14561874/compare/alt1) [two](https://github.com/tschaub/stackoverflow-q14561874/compare/alt2) alternatives.

The problem with the approach above is that `Target.prototype` is not properly set up in the script scope.  See the static [`ScriptableObject.defineClass()`](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/3b36c861d20773d8719ab5b400aea625ce71bc02/src/org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptableObject.java#L1162-L1202) method for details on how to properly define prototypes in a script scope.

You have a couple alternatives for providing the `Target` constructor to your scripts.  The [first alternative](https://github.com/tschaub/stackoverflow-q14561874/compare/alt1) would be to always define the `Target` constructor for all scripts.  This works well if you know ahead of time that you want `Target` to be globally available.  This basically comes down to the following:

```
final Context context = Context.enter();
try {
  final ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
  ScriptableObject.defineClass(scope, Target.class, false, true);
  context.evaluateString(scope, script, "script", 1, null);
  // etc.
} finally {
  Context.exit();
}
```

If instead you want the script author to decide which constructors are necessary, the [second alternative](https://github.com/tschaub/stackoverflow-q14561874/compare/alt2) is to provide the `defineClass` function to scripts.  With this function, script authors can "import" any scriptable objects on their class path (which may be more than you want to allow).  To provide the `defineClass` functions to scripts, do the following after entering the context:

```
final Context context = Context.enter();
try {
  final ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
  scope.defineFunctionProperties(
          new String[] {"defineClass"},
          Global.class,
          ScriptableObject.DONTENUM);

  context.evaluateString(scope, script, "script", 1, null);
  // etc.
} finally {
  Context.exit();
}
```

And then, the JavaScript author makes use of the `Target` constructor with the following:

```
defineClass("com.acme.rhino.Target");
// whatever `getClassName()` returns is now available
var target = new Target();
```

In both of the above branches, I've made a couple other changes that set you up better if you add more to the `Target` constructor.  The zero argument constructor doesn't need the `@JSConstructor` annotation.  If you later want to have a constructor that accepts arguments, this zero argument constructor will be used as the prototype constructor, and you can use the `@JSConstructor` annotation on a method that will be used to initialize your object.  Depending on how you author this constructor method, it will become important to use the `new` keyword in your JavaScript.

In short, the `Packages.com.acme...` syntax is *not* useful for getting access to `ScriptableObject` constructors from scripts.

Comment: Just a note that your github links don't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I get it working (very similar code) by using the new operator. In your example doing

```
 function evaluate() {
      var t = new Target();
      ...
```

should work as well.