# Javascript - adding function to prototype results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to add a function to the `BattleState` object.
I am using the prototype method as I don't want the function to be serialised, as described in [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

This is roughly how I have my code set up, when I call the `getPlayerStateFromBattleState` function, I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot find default value for object."
I assume it is the function that I've added to the prototype that can't be found, but I may be wrong. Does anyone know what is causing this?

```
function BattleState() {
  this.player1 = new PlayerState();
  this.player1.id = 1;
  this.player2 = new PlayerState();
  this.player2.id = 2;
};


BattleState.prototype.getPlayerStateFromBattleState = function(thisPlayerId) {
  if (this.player1.id == thisPlayerId) {
    return this.player1;
  } else if (this.player2.id == thisPlayerId) {
    return this.player2;
  } else {
    // Error
  }
}


var battleState = new BattleState();

// This line resutls in "TypeError: Cannot find default value for object."
var playerState = battleState.getPlayerStateFromBattleState(1);
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What line of code is associated with that error? If the code you posted is only "roughly" the code with which you're experiencing problems, get rid of it and post the *actual* code. This stuff here looks fine.

Comment: What is PlayerState?

Comment: Do you use Rhino? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561874/calling-jsfunction-from-javascript-typeerror-cannot-find-default-value-for-ob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem:

```
// This line resutls in "TypeError: Cannot find default value for object."
console.log(battleState.getPlayerStateFromBattleState(2));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kg85w55e/

The given code just worked. I think there is something in your PlayerState Class.
Could you Adjust your question and include your PlayerState Class?

Comment: You're right, the problem is in the PlayerState, thanks!